# print something else below the renderDataTable in shiny, R

Tags: r, shiny

I've tried to print some  other strings below or above the table in a tab page (via tabPanel, renderDataTable and dataTableOutput) in shiny, R. How to implement it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("show_data"))
```

Change to:

```
tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("show_data"), HTML("My exta text"))
```

Or is you need more control you could use:

```
tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("show_data"), verbatimTextOutput("extra_text"))
```

where extra_text is a renderText function

Comment: Where could I get the detailed manual of shiny? It seems no such thing in the page of shiny in RStudio. Thank you.

Comment: Many of the examples with just a mainpanel do have multiple outputs I think. The http://shiny.rstudio.com/ site has excellent tutorials and the gallery has very good examples where you can see the code, some with multiple outputs.